# parallelism in shell data pipeline

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, pipe, pipeline

So I am reading [this](https://adamdrake.com/command-line-tools-can-be-235x-faster-than-your-hadoop-cluster.html) article on how shell commands can be really fast and faster than a hadoop cluster for processing large amounts of data.

I read that **in a data pipeline, shell commands are processed in parallel.**

I tried

```
sleep 3 | echo "Hello world."
```

It prints Hello World and goes into sleep mode, which exits after 3s

But when i did,

```
echo "Hello World" | sleep 2
```

It just went into sleep. Hello World was not printed

Can anyone explain it to me why this happens? 
If the commands are executed in parallel, shouldn't Hello World get printed either way?

Comment: Though this question is fairly good, this is highly subjective and may not be related to the StackOverflow, as its a site dedicated for programming. This question would be really appropriate in Unix & Linux StackExchange

Comment: The article you link to says *command-line tools*, not "shell commands".  That might seem like semantics but they are different.  *command-line tools* are external programs, unrelated to the shell.  The pipeline `|` shown *is* shell related, although these *anonymous pipes* can be setup by any general purpose language, not just a shell.

Comment: It isn't `sleep`'s job to look at what it receives from other commands, nor to output it for you to see. It just hangs around a bit, then exits.

Answer (score 1):

pipe(`|`) is made to deal with one command's output to be send as input to another command for example:

`echo "hello there"` will simply print `hello there` but when put a `|` and append a `sed` code after it eg-->  `echo "hello there" | sed "s/hello/hi/"` then it will print `hi there` because echo's output works as standard input for `sed` command.

So in your 1st case:

```
sleep 3 | echo "Hello world."
```

sleep don't send any output to `echo` and it only runs a sleep process in back end and standard output from echo command shows us `Hello world` on screen.

But in 2nd case: when `echo` is sending standard output to sleep command as standard input I believe it doesn't take it since sleep only takes parameters(digit values) to let it know how much time it needs to put sleep process so it and moreover it is NOT suppose to show any standard output on screen so that print doesn't happen there.

Answer (score 0):

The vertical bar, `|`, between the two commands is called a pipe. It tells the shell that we want to use the output of the command on the left as the input to the command on the right.

In your example, `sleep` does nothing with the output of `echo` .